# Touchpad gestures to change workspace

Tags: touchpad, workspaces, gestures

I was talking to a friend who owns a Mac. He has his set up so that when he swipes three fingers across his touchpad, it moves to the workspace in that direction. Is it possible to set this up in Ubuntu?

Comment: I can't personally vouch for whether this method works, but there is a program called `EasyStroke` that may do what you're looking for. See [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859936) for setup instructions.

Comment: https://github.com/arunhedcet/mac-gestures

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your touchpad (hardware) needs to support this feature and you then may need to configure your touchpad (Ubuntu automatically recognizes and enables some hardware).

One common drier is synaptic. You can enable two finger scrolling from the mouse and touchpad section in the control panel.

[image: control panel]

If you wish additional options you will need to manually edit a few configuration files and the options are hardware dependent.

There is a debugging page here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection

Take a look at that page, if you can identify your hardware we can perhaps give you more specific assistance.

An example of hardware specific guides: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicTrackpad

### Consider easystroke

You can also take a look at "easystroke"

http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/wiki

Here is a demo of easystroke in action: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CagAEgXAAzA

Comment: I don't see the horizontal scrolling option on Ubuntu 14.04. Does this have to do with my hardware config?

Comment: is there a solution for Ubuntu 16.04??

Answer (score 30):

## How to change workspaces using touchpad gestures in ubuntu

*Complete tutorial using touchegg, easystroke is better to be used with mouse rather than touchpad.*

*In case you are using unity you may experience some conflicts with build-in gestures. The tutorial I gained information from deals with this issue (please see the link below). I didn't have any build in gestures, so this how-to provides only information how to set up things.*

1. Download [Touchegg](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/):

   ```
   sudo apt install touchegg
   ```
2. run it, but kill just after that, it will create a file

   ```
   ~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf
   ```
3. open it in an editor you desire and add those three lines below into the name="All" section

   ```
   <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="RIGHT">
      <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Left</action>
   </gesture>
   <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="3" direction="LEFT">
      <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Right</action>
   </gesture>
   ```
4. Run touchegg to try it out

   ```
   touchegg &
   ```
5. Edit the config file as you wish and then add touchegg to the list of startup applications

The tutorial I mentioned can be found [here](http://task3.cc/1068/os-x-like-multitouch-gestures-for-macbook-pro-running-ubuntu-12-10/) - there some things out of date (you don't have to compile it). Anyway thx to the creator!

Comment: Gestures are not recognized on my computer :(

Comment: This is not working on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Yeah, not working on my XPS13 either, running 15.04, or (today) 16.04 nightly. I wonder if there's a useful way to trouble shoot it, since the O/S does recognise 3-finger taps (mostly), but touchegg isn't interested.

Comment: It's working fine :D with elementary OS

Comment: is there a solution for Ubuntu 16.04??

Comment: worked like a charm for me on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Not working on my case, Ubuntu 16.04 is detecting two fingers scroll but not multitouch like 3 fingers. Need to install something more?

Comment: I've got 4 workspaces arranged in a 2x2 grid: How can I reconfigure the 3-finger (or 4-finger) swipe on my Thinkpad touchpad to switch between these four (rather than only left <-> right with the 3-fingers) ?

Edit: just figured out I can use the 3-finger left <-> right "repeatedly" and browse all four workspaces, albeit not in a **2x2**, but rather a 1x4 "grid". How to make it 2x2, with **left <-> right and up <-> down** ?

Answer (score 26):

## Comfortable Swipe

Try [comfortable-swipe](https://github.com/Hikari9/comfortable-swipe). Provides 3-finger and 4-finger gestures for switching workspaces, plus a couple more like the window spread in mac.

This also uses xdotool, but more comfy than the laggy libinput-gestures if you ask me.

Comment: works with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Works smoothly with Kubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.10 you have to replace "libinput-debug-events" in src/comfortable-swipe.cpp with "libinput debug-events" three times. Than install with " bash install"

Comment: It works on my 18.04 but takes several seconds to respond and my fans go crazy fast and noisy making it not worth it. Nothing special appears on htop during this time.

Comment: Worked in 5 min, nothing else worked after hours. Brilliant, thanks for sharing !

Comment: Works on my Dell G5 with 18.04, make sure to run the permissions setting it shows in the README and log in+out. Up and down swipes work perfectly!

Comment: Worked like a charm on Ubuntu 20.04. Just note that, in the instructions given on the project's Github, it says to logout and then log back in. That doesn't work - you gotta restart your computer.

Comment: Works perfectly well on XPS 9500 15" with Ubuntu 20.10 (Gnome). Didn't need to restart, just log out and in again.

Answer (score 12):

The following worked for me on Ubuntu 16.04 and a 2017 Dell XPS 13 (9360):

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl libinput-tools
git clone http://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
cd libinput-gestures
sudo ./libinput-gestures-setup install
```

Restart your computer after the above steps. My `~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf` is:

```
gesture swipe down  xdotool key ctrl+alt+Up
gesture swipe up    xdotool key ctrl+alt+Down
gesture swipe right xdotool key ctrl+alt+Left
gesture swipe left  xdotool key ctrl+alt+Right
```

Comment: Thanks, Working on 17.10 on HP Envy 13 with Synaptics Touchpad

Comment: This works perfectly, just make sure you have matching shortcuts configured in KDE as well, since xdotool just fires off key combos.

Comment: not working on an Acer with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: not working on a Huawei Matebook with Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution: 4 fingers and natural direction.

```
 <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="4" direction="RIGHT">
       <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Right</action>
    </gesture>
    <gesture type="DRAG" fingers="4" direction="LEFT">
       <action type="SEND_KEYS">Control+Alt+Left</action>
    </gesture>
```

Comment: What program does one need for this?

Comment: @g3mini touchegg, as tsusanka suggested

Comment: Thanks =) When I asked his/her answer wasn't there yet =D

Answer (score 1):

I used the synaptics driver with xdotool to do that...

For speed of my macbook touchpad:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf
# Touchpad Speedup
        Option "AccelFactor" "0.025"
        Option "MinSpeed" "0.80"
        Option "MaxSpeed" "0.95"
        Option "FingerHigh" "55"
        Option "FingerLow" "45"
```

For 3 fingers gesture change workspace:

```
sudo nano ~/.config/libinput-gestures.conf
gesture swipe up        3       xdotool key ctrl+alt+Up
gesture swipe down      3       xdotool key ctrl+alt+Down
gesture swipe left      3       xdotool key ctrl+alt+Left
gesture swipe right     3       xdotool key ctrl+alt+Right
```

Answer (score 0):

Like already mentioned:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER input
sudo apt-get install xdotool wmctrl libinput-tools
git clone http://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures
cd libinput-gestures
sudo ./libinput-gestures-setup install
```

But you have to go to:

```
cd ~/libinput-gestures
```

and edit the created libinput-gestures.conf:

```
gedit libinput-gestures.conf
```

And then make safe the following is set correctly:

```
gesture swipe down  xdotool key ctrl+alt+Up
gesture swipe up    xdotool key ctrl+alt+Down
gesture swipe right xdotool key ctrl+alt+Left
gesture swipe left  xdotool key ctrl+alt+Right
```

> Remember: You have to set the key combinations in the Ubuntu settings to the ones shown above - these should be the default.