# Are there other gestures for the Synaptics Touchpad besides two-finger scrolling?

Tags: 12.04, multi-touch, synaptics, gestures

I have a Synaptics Touchpad on my Dell XPS 14z and I was wondering if there was any way I could enable some gestures besides two-finger scrolling.

Are there any special drivers i need? 
I've read somewhere that 12.04 has had some issues with multitouch gestures but I'm not exactly sure.
If there is a way, could someone give me instructions on how to enable (or get) these features?

I found some [evidence](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/issues/detail?id=148) that touchegg may not work with 12.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Touchegg is designed to bring multi-touch (touchpad) functionality to
>   Linux based operating systems. In layman’s term, it is an open source
>   multi-touch gesture recognizer for GNU/Linux which is backed by C++,
>   Qt and uTouch-geis library. With TouchEgg, you can define what type of
>   actions are to be initiated for a specific multi-touch gesture.
>   Numerous actions can be assigned for multi-touch gestures such as
>   maximizing or minimizing windows, resizing applications, switching to
>   desktop view, etc. It requires uTouch and evedev libraries.
>
> Touchegg comes with some pre-enabled gestures, however gestures can be
>   enabled by editing the config file. It allows  three-fingers pinch,
>   two, three, four and five finger tap and two to four finger swipes.

#### How to install?

add this ppa,`ppa:utouch-team/daily` as,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:utouch-team/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

#### Which gestures are supported?

check [here](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/AllGestures)

#### How to use?

config file location `~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf`

The config file can be edited in the following way:

open config file.

```
gedit ~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf
```

get list of actions [here](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/wiki/AllActions)

```
# THREE FINGERS DRAG
[THREE_FINGERS_DRAG_UP]
action=MAXIMIZE_RESTORE_WINDOW
settings=
[THREE_FINGERS_DRAG_DOWN]
action=MINIMIZE_WINDOW
settings=
```

Similarly, in the example below, the four finger drag gesture is configured to switch to the desktop display.

```
[FOUR_FINGERS_DRAG_DOWN]
action=SHOW_DESKTOP
settings=
```

With Touchegg, users can easily define multi-touch gestures in order to get the Mac like multi-touch experience on their Linux systems.

you can watch a brief demonstration video. [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=_jRiEFA7ExY) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ek4QaFQ1qo&feature=player_embedded)

I found also [this one](http://www.ceh-photo.de/blog/?p=320)

though I haven't tried it.

Comment: Could this be a problem for me? 

http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/issues/detail?id=148

Comment: may be but give it a try. if it does then vote for issue on launchpad.

Comment: How do I access the .conf? (I'm slightly new to this)

Comment: ~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf

Comment: From the terminal? permission denied.
I know I know, I barely understand anything about the terminal. Every time I open it I end up screwing something up.

Comment: how it can happen it's in your home directory and is owned by you. BTW try `gedit ~/.config/touchegg/touchegg.conf`

Comment: I don't understand why that happened. I'll try the other one.

gedit worked.

Comment: No, touchegg didn't work.

Here's a question for a new user like me.
If there is ever a fix for that bug I gave a link to, will it be fixed in an update or something, and just work? Or do I have to apply the fix manually?

Comment: if you have installed it. you'll get notified via update manager whenever a fix or update is released.

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:utouch-team/daily` gives "Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:utouch-team/daily'. Please check that the PPA name or format is correct". What to do?

Comment: I think there is more up-to-date info here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/92169/touchpad-gestures-to-change-workspace

Comment: it doesn't work on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Not as of `07 17, 2012`.  Ubuntu recommends using touchegg, which is has an API incompatibility with the latest version of utouch in Ubuntu according to this [ticket](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/issues/detail?id=148). Ubuntu's Unity has some multi-touch features involving 2+ fingers, but they are not configurable without modifying source code and recompiling*. If you are interested in recompiling Unity, and know C++, here is the [relevant source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/5.0/view/head:/plugins/unityshell/src/GestureEngine.cpp).

Here is the [Ubuntu wiki for Unity's multitouch features](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/#Supported_Gestures).

Comment: [Unity's multitouch features](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/#Supported_Gestures)