# Three finger swipe to change workspaces

Tags: workspace-switcher, gestures

I am looking for a way to make three finger swipe to the left or right change to different workspace on ubuntu 15.04 with unity environment. Best I found was a comment down in [Touchpad gestures to change workspace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92169/touchpad-gestures-to-change-workspace) , but it looks out-of-date and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Touchegg might be a good solution for Gnome or Arch linux users, but [XSwipe](https://github.com/iberianpig/xSwipe) is the best for Ubuntu with Unity I have used so far. Check it out!

The configuration may take a couple of hours but it worth.