# Touchpad gestures to change workspace on KDE Plasma

Tags: touchpad, kde, plasma, touchegg

I want to enable touch-pad gesture on KDE 16.04. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/92169/600715) that for Ubuntu and I tried it but is not working. How can I make it working on kde ? 
Thanks