# configure vertical scrolling using three fingers

Tags: xubuntu, mouse, synaptics, scrolling

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and want to set up three finger scrolling (and four finger scrolling) on my laptop. I already have two-finger scrolling enabled.

While searching I saw other people needing to configure three finger to change other things except three finger scrolling. Am I missing something from [Touchpad_Synaptics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics)?

Synaptics reported the following values:

```
Synaptics Capabilities (347):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

These values mean (from left to right):

```
1: Device has a physical left button
0: Device does not have a physical middle button
1: Device has a physical right button
1: Device does support two-finger detection
1: Device does support three-finger detection
1: Device can configure vertical resolution
1: Device can configure horizontal resolution
```

Is there a config or a way to add three finger and four finger scrolling? Can someone point me in the right direction?

*I have updated my question with links to similar things*

- [another stackoverflow question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92169/touchpad-gestures-to-change-workspace)
- [github - comfortable-swipe](https://github.com/Hikari9/comfortable-swipe)
- [manjaro forums with gnome - but im using i3](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-three-finger-gestures-on-synaptics-touchpad-using-gnome/20848)
- [same issue that i am mentioning here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1323109&page=3&s=aa063d5b952ccc260d5a647515d21647)
- [may be a possible solution but difficult to follow](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117981)
- [opposite to what i am trying to achieve](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510884/disable-scroll-by-3-and-4-fingers-on-synaptics-touchpad)
- [for window overview](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues/1182)

Comment: IIRC the synaptics input driver supports detection of up to five fingers, but only tracks the positions of the first two fingers. A three-finger motion command wouldn't make sense then.

Comment: @danzel using three finger detection, others configure changing workspace and other stuff, if that can be done, there must be a way to do this also?

Comment: And how did the others do it? If you find a reference, please [edit] your question and add a link. I can think of a lot of workarounds, but the input driver doesn't support it, and therefore you can't configure it to make it work. Run `synclient` in a terminal, it will list all configurable options of synaptics. The only three-finger-related options are tap and click.

Comment: @danzel i have updated the question with links